# CSS position Sticky and Z-Index overlay/modal

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

i have a problem with the position: sticky and z-index

I want my modal in the sticky-element to be overlayed by the overlay.
With position: relative it works: the modal is before the overlay. But when I use Sticky the modal is behind the overlay.

Hope it's understandable what I mean.
Here's the example:

```css
.sticky {
    position: sticky; /* <-- dosen't work */
    /* position: relative; /* <-- work */
    top: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 200vh;
    background: red;
}

.modal {
    z-index: 1000;

    position: fixed; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.overlay {
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;


    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="sticky">
    <div class="modal">modal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind adding an example of how it should look?

Comment: Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOQVbG
(position: sticky replaced with relative)

Answer (score 22):

When you set `position: relative`, the `.modal` element is relative to the body because it has `position: fixed`. As such, the z-index value of 1000 put it in foreground.

When you use `position: sticky`, the `.sticky` element is positionned, with the default z-index value. Therefore, it positions itself in background because `.overlay`'s z-index value of 999. `.modal` being a child of `.sticky`, it will never be able to go in front of `.overlay`.

You must change the structure of your HTML, or simply add a z-index on your `.sticky` element.

Comment: I had this problem in react. There it can be solved by using a portal

Comment: I added z index on my sticky element but still it does not show in front

Comment: I have the same problem with Blazor. I tried with z-index but it didn't work. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had sticky element which should go above other sticky

```
sticky1:
  z-index: 10000
sticky2:
 z-index: 1
 absolute3:
  z-index: 10001
```

Above will never work (absolute3 will not appear above sticky1)

The solution:

change sticky2 z-index to z-index at least 10000