# Jquery modals trigger button position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking to trigger different sticky buttons/modals for each of my sections. 
I want on click hit, a modal popup appears with all the article details.

Everything works fine so far. 
My problem is that when first modal is open with all the article details, 
I can see the button from the second modals. I tried organizing some specs of the z-index but is not working with the sticking class of my divs.

I was wondering what I have to modify in my Javascript code to make visible just the article without any buttons of modals shown.

Any ideas to what I should fix in my fiddle to make it work correctly? 
Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/48rd76mp/5/

my snippet code is here below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="CAT is a designer and art director" />







<!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1-->
<!--SECTION-1-->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->  
<div class="img-container" id="uno">
<img src="https://media.endclothing.com/end-features/prodfeatures/5ee628543c59bce18d2dd4614c7aa1b5ca8bca0f_end.-hiroshi-fujiwara-moncler-genius-interview12.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky">
<div class="sticky-button">      
<!--MODAL-1-->  
<button class='btn-1 modal-btn'>Open Modal 1</button><div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('YourModalBox').style.display='none'" class="close-button topright">&times;</span><div class="modal"><span>
  Title Description-1  <br>
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-1-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1--><!--1-->







<!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2-->
<!--SECTION-2-->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->  
<div class="img-container" id="due">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/ec/76/90ec76614129cba11f178821e59a99f8.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky">
<div class="sticky-button">      
<!--MODAL-2-->  
<button class='btn-2 modal-btn'>Open Modal 2</button><div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox2">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('YourModalBox2').style.display='none'" class="close-button topright">&times;</span><div class="modal"><span>
  Title Description-1  <br>
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-2-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2--><!--2-->  











<!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3-->
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->     
<!-- img-container -->   
<!-- img-container -->   
<div class="img-container" id="tre">
<img src="https://media.gq.com/photos/5da1fd854e024d0009825bfd/4:3/w_2520,h_1891,c_limit/pharrell-williams-cover-gq-november-2019-02-16x9.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
<div class="sticky"><div class="sticky-button">
<!--MODAL-3-->  
<button class='btn-3 modal-btn'>Tomoaki Nagao info</button>
<div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox3">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('YourModalBox3').style.display='none'" class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal"><span>Title Description-3  <br>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div></div>
<!--MODAL-3-->  
</div></div></div>
<!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3--><!--3-->  











<!-- REMOVE!! -->
<div class="break-2"></div>
<!-- REMOVE!! -->
```

```
.close-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.topright {
  position: fixed!important;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}


*{ z-index: 999999;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}



body, html{
font-size: 16px;
}


/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
.img-container { 
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding:20px;  
   background-color: white;
   justify-content: center;  
   z-index:0;

}
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.img-container  {
       padding:20px;  
       height: 80vh;   
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.img-container  {
     padding:20px; 
      height: 82vh;   
}
}
#uno{background:purple;}
#due{background: yellow;}
#tre{background:black;}


img {
   position:absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
   height:100%;
   z-index:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
        img {
        width:95%;
           height:80%;
        object-fit: cover;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
    img {
        width:95%;
        height:100%;
        object-fit: cover;
}
}





.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 20px;  
  right:20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}


.sticky-button {  
  background: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  /*padding: 6px 10px;*/
  color:white;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: auto;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
.sticky-button {
     width: auto;
    font-size: 0.8rem;

   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.sticky-button {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 0.8rem;

   }
}


.sticky-button-description {
   color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.75);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-weight:400;

   font-family:helvetica;
   display:inline;
    letter-spacing: normal;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width:450px){
.sticky-button-description{

   }
}
.sticky-button-break {
   padding:0.3rem;
  }
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/
/*container-video*/







.break{height:200px;
   width:100%;
   background:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;}

.break-2{height:900px;
   width:100%;
   background:red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;}













.btn-1 {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color:#3E3E3E;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: transform .3s ease;
     z-index:100;
}

.btn-1:active {
    transform: scale(10.9);
   opacity:0;
    z-index:20;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    z-index:100;

}


.btn-2 {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color:#3E3E3E;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: transform .3s ease;
   z-index:50;

}

.btn-2:active {
  position:sticky;
    transform: scale(10.9);
  z-index:50;

}

.btn-3 {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color:#3E3E3E;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    z-index:30;

}

.btn-3:active {
    transform: scale(10.9);
   z-index:30;

}


/* Modal */
.overlay {
   position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;/*rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);*/
  pointer-events: none;
}


.overlay, .modal {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.overlay--open {
  opacity: 1;

  pointer-events: auto;
}

.overlay--open .modal {
  opacity: 1;

  transform: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;

  width: 100%;
  margin: 15vh auto 0;
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
  transform: translateY(80%) scale(.8);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, 0, 1.3);
  transition-delay: .4s;
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:400;
}
/*MODAL TRIGGER*/
/*MODAL TRIGGER*/
```

```
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn');
let overlay;
modalBtns.forEach(btn => {

  btn.onclick = function() {
     overlay = this.nextElementSibling
       overlay.classList.add('overlay--open');
  }
})


function closeModal() {
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay--open');
}

function onDocumentKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeModal();
    }
}

function onDocumentClick(e) {
    if (e.target === overlay) {
        closeModal();

    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false);
```

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105658/css-position-sticky-and-z-index-overlay-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can try my changes:

- Moved modals outside of `.sticky` element
- Made `.modal-btn`'s `onclick` move up DOM parents and find `nextElementSibling`
- Fixed the crazy `z-index` that was on `*{}` in CSS
- Fixed `z-index` of the `.modal-btn`
- Added `z-index` to `.overlay`
- Removed the `.close-button` click event
- Added a global clear of `.overlay--open` from `.overlay` when `.close-button` is clicked.

---

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o0aq92r7/2/

---

```js
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn');
const closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.close-button');

let overlay;
modalBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function() {
     overlay = this.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling
   overlay.classList.add('overlay--open');
  }
});
closeBtns.forEach(cBtn => {
    cBtn.onclick = function() {
        const overlayElements = document.querySelectorAll('.overlay');
        overlayElements.forEach(overlay => {
            overlay.classList.remove('overlay--open');
        });
    }
});

function onDocumentKeyUp(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 27) {
  closeModal();
 }
}

function onDocumentClick(e) {
 if (e.target === overlay) {
  closeModal();
 }
}

document.addEventListener('click', onDocumentClick, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false);
```

```css
.close-button {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap
  }
  
  .topright {
    position: fixed!important;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  
  
  * {
    z-index: 1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  
  
  body, html{
  font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  .img-container { 
     display: flex;
     height: 100vh;
      justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:20px;  
     background-color: white;
     justify-content: center;  
     z-index:0;
  
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
  .img-container  {
         padding:20px;  
         height: 80vh;   
  }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width:450px){
  .img-container  {
       padding:20px; 
        height: 82vh;   
  }
  }
  #uno{background:purple;}
  #due{background: yellow;}
  #tre{background:black;}
  
  
  img {
     position:absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
     height:100%;
     z-index:0;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
          img {
          width:95%;
             height:80%;
          object-fit: cover;
  }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width:450px){
      img {
          width:95%;
          height:100%;
          object-fit: cover;
  }
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  .sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 20px;  
    right:20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  
  .sticky-button {  
    background: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      box-shadow:0 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    /*padding: 6px 10px;*/
    color:white;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 24px;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  
  @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
  .sticky-button {
       width: auto;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
    
     }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width:450px){
  .sticky-button {
      width: auto;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
    
     }
  }
  
  
  .sticky-button-description {
     color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.75);
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      font-weight:400;
  
     font-family:helvetica;
     display:inline;
      letter-spacing: normal;
    }
  @media only screen and (max-width:450px){
  .sticky-button-description{
      
     }
  }
  .sticky-button-break {
     padding:0.3rem;
    }
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  /*container-video*/
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  .break{height:200px;
     width:100%;
     background:black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
  
  .break-2{height:900px;
     width:100%;
     background:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  .btn-1 {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 24px;
      color: white;
      background-color:#3E3E3E;
      padding: 10px 18px;
      font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      transition: transform .3s ease;
       z-index:2;
  }
  
  .btn-1:active {
      transform: scale(10.9);
     opacity:0;
      z-index:20;
        transition: transform .3s ease;
      z-index:100;
   
  }
  
  
  .btn-2 {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 24px;
      color: white;
      background-color:#3E3E3E;
      padding: 10px 18px;
      font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      transition: transform .3s ease;
     z-index:50;
  
  }
  
  .btn-2:active {
    position:sticky;
      transform: scale(10.9);
    z-index:50;
     
  }
  
  .btn-3 {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 24px;
      color: white;
      background-color:#3E3E3E;
      padding: 10px 18px;
      font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0px 12px 20px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      transition: transform .3s ease;
      z-index:30;
   
  }
  
  .btn-3:active {
      transform: scale(10.9);
     z-index:30;
  
  }
  
  
  /* Modal */
  .overlay {
     position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;/*rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);*/
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
  
  .overlay, .modal {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  .overlay--open {
    opacity: 1;
   
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  
  .overlay--open .modal {
    opacity: 1;
  
    transform: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    position: fixed;
  
    width: 100%;
    margin: 15vh auto 0;
    background: black;
    color:#fff;
    transform: translateY(80%) scale(.8);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3, 0, 0, 1.3);
    transition-delay: .4s;
    text-align: center;
      font-size: 26px;
    font-weight:400;
  }
  /*MODAL TRIGGER*/
  /*MODAL TRIGGER*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="CAT is a designer and art director" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img-container" id="uno">
        <img src="https://assets.vogue.com/photos/5cd30b6bd2f46d2eca29ab09/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/virgil-abloh-vogue-june-2019-issue.jpg"
            alt="Smiley face">
        <div class="sticky">
            <div class="sticky-button">
                <button class='btn-1 modal-btn'>Open Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-1-->
        <div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox">
            <span class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
            <div class="modal"><span>
                    Title Description-1  <br>
                    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                    laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
                    architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
                    aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
                    voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
                    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui
                    ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-1-->
    </div>

    <div class="img-container" id="due">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/ec/76/90ec76614129cba11f178821e59a99f8.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
        <div class="sticky">
            <div class="sticky-button">
                <button class='btn-2 modal-btn'>Karl info</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-2-->
        <div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox2">
            <span class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
            <div class="modal"><span>
                    Title Description-1  <br>
                    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                    laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
                    architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
                    aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
                    voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
                    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui
                    ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-2-->
    </div>

    <div class="img-container" id="tre">
        <img src="https://media.gq.com/photos/5da1fd854e024d0009825bfd/4:3/w_2520,h_1891,c_limit/pharrell-williams-cover-gq-november-2019-02-16x9.jpg"
            alt="Smiley face">
        <div class="sticky">
            <div class="sticky-button">
                <button class='btn-3 modal-btn'>Tomoaki Nagao info</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-3-->
        <div class="overlay" id="YourModalBox3">
            <span class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
            <div class="modal"><span>Title Description-3  <br>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus
                    error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae
                    ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
                    ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur
                    magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                    Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
                    consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt</span></div>
        </div>
        <!--MODAL-3-->
    </div>


    <!-- REMOVE!! -->
    <div class="break-2"></div>
    <!-- REMOVE!! -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @biotox for the explanation, work perfectly ‍♂️