# Material Table icon overlapping with column name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

While scrolling down, the icons would overlap with the column name before going out of view. This only happens for the action column.

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO2Ps.png)

This is the code for my table column:

```
    const [columns2, setColumns2] = useState([
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname', initialEditValue: 'initial edit value' },
    { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
    {
        title: 'Birth Place',
        field: 'birthCity',
        lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
    },
]);

const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },

]);
```

This is the code for the table:

```
 <MaterialTable
                title="Editable Preview"
                columns={columns2}
                data={data}
                options={{
                    pageSize: 20,
                    search: false,
                    showTitle: false,
                    toolbar: false,
                    thirdSortClick: false,
                    headerStyle: {
                        position: "sticky",
                        top: "0"
                    },
                    maxBodyHeight: "300px"
                }}
                editable={{
                    onRowAdd: newData =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                setData([...data, newData]);

                                resolve();
                            }, 1000)
                        }),
                    onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                const dataUpdate = [...data];
                                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                                dataUpdate[index] = newData;
                                setData([...dataUpdate]);

                                resolve();
                            }, 1000)
                        }),
                    onRowDelete: oldData =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                const dataDelete = [...data];
                                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                                dataDelete.splice(index, 1);
                                setData([...dataDelete]);

                                resolve()
                            }, 1000)
                        }),
                }}
            />
```

I haven't seen anyone with this problem before, please help. Thank you.

Comment: This can be a problem: headerStyle: {
                        position: "sticky",
                        top: "0"
                    },

Comment: this might hint to the [source of your problem: ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105658/css-position-sticky-and-z-index-overlay-modal)

Comment: Actually, yes, that would solve the problem. However, I want the column names to always be at the top. Is it possible?

Comment: header transparent so it overlaps! Use dark color in the background or zIndex to resolve this.